# Scaleable GUI Box/Labels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My GUI Boxes and Labels are set by Coordinates. How would I set them to scale with resolution and screen size as they go off screen on build. The first IF statement the GUI displayed on the top left of screen and then next displays on the top right! Code examples would be very helpful!

```
public void OnGUI()
{
    if ((isClicked) && (cdrwModel))
    {
        GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(5, 5, 400, 400), "<color=cyan><size=30>This is the </size></color>" + "<color=cyan><size=30>" + this.cdrw + "</size></color>");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(15, 35, 400, 400), "Press <TAB> for more information");
        if (showGui) 
        {
            GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
            GUI.Box(new Rect(1000, 5, 400, 400), "What You Should Know");
            GUI.Label(new Rect(1135, 5, 400, 400), "___________________");
            GUI.Label(new Rect(1145, 23, 400, 400), "<color=cyan><size=20>The </size></color>" + "<color=cyan><size=20>" + this.cdrw + "</size></color>");    
            foreach (var file in _puzzlesFile)
            {
                GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
                GUI.Label(new Rect(1000, 50, 400, 400), file);
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Screen class to get current Screen.width and Screen.height and create something to recalculate your GUI coordinates when it changes. If your game camera doesn't uses entire screen you can get Camera.current.pixelWidth/pixelHeight to do the same.

If you want a responsive UI you should avoid coordinates and use GUILayout instead of GUI class to declare your components, it is way better and easier to adjust without a lot of handmade calculations that can (and probably will) blow your performance out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Screen.width for width and x position of GUI and Screen.height for height and y position of GUI.
For Example:, for a screen resoulution for 1024:640

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(Screen.width/10, Screen.height/10, Screen.width/3, Screen.height/5), "What You Should Know");
```

will create a Gui box same with

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(102.4f, 64, 341.3f, 128), "What You Should Know");
```

but first one will be responsive.